# Updating object in DB? (Node.js w/ Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
        array: []
});

var PSchema = mongoose.model('objects', mySchema);
```

I've added 1 element called 'hello' to the array property in a schema object

```
var newObject = new PSchema;
newObject.array.push('hello');
newObject.save(function (err) {});
```

I want to update the schema object to add 'hello2' to the array property if and only if hello2 doesn't already exist in the array.

Is this possible with mongoose? If so, how do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `find()` function and then perform an `update`.

```
PSchema.find({},function(err,docs){
docs.forEach(function(doc){
if(doc.array.indexOf("hello2") == -1)
{
    doc.array.push("hello2");
    doc.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            //error
        }
    });
}
})
})
```